# get useLocation props from Route : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isNew')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm new to reactjs, I want to access to my component `Bdc` using two ways first when I click on a button in another component and the other way when I access the component using its path directly in search bar.

First way is working using `useLocation`

```
<Button 
   variant="contained" 
   onClick={() => navigate("/nouveauBdc", {state: {id: '', isNew: true}})}>
         NOUVEAU BON DE COMMANDE
 </Button>
```

In my component I can read state sent from `navigate("/nouveauBdc", {state: {id: '', isNew: true}})`

but the second way when I put the path of my component in search bar `http://localhost:3001/nouveauBdc` I got this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'isNew')

`Bdc` component : here is the line from where I got the error :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    setBdcState(location.state as BdcProps);
  }, [location])

React.useEffect(() => {
    if(!bdcState.isNew){
      //get data
    }
  }, [bdcState.isNew]) // the line error
```

my Routes
I put the Link to pass the state from here but is not working

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/nouveauBdc" element={<ProtectedRoutes/>}>
         <Route path="/nouveauBdc" element={<Bdc />} />
      </Route>
          
      <Route path="*" element={<h1>404 - Page non trouvée</h1>} />
      <Route path="/accessDenied" element={<h1>403 - Accès interdit</h1>} />
    </Routes>
    <Link to={'nouveauBdc'} state={{ state: {id: '', isNew: true} }} >Page 1</Link>

  </BrowserRouter>,
```

ProtectedRoutes.tsx

```
const user = () => {
    if(userAuth)){
      return(
        <Outlet/>
      );
    } else {       
      return(
        <Navigate to="/accessDenied"/>
      );          
    } 
  }
  
  return(
    <div>
      {user()}
    </div>
    );
```

Please is there any solution to send state as well when access component directly (search bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the state directly from the location bar, it will always be null (and null, of course, doesn't have any properties, so you get the error).

If you want to display the component when the location is inserted in the URL bar, you should use `location.search` instead. That will add a query to your url, such as `?bcdState=new` which you can read when the component loads similar to `location.state`.

Comment: Got it! Thank you. Pease is it not possible to pass the state from Route like using Link component or something else ?

Comment: It is possible to pass the state from Link to another page, but it will be lost when you reload the page or directly insert the URL. You can pass the state using `<Link to={{pathname: "/nouveauBdc", state: { id: '', isNew: true } }}/>`

Comment: Hi, @Idrizi.A But if I want `id` to show its value then I couldn't show it anymore, after reloading too! Anyhow, it is going to be lost. As you mentioned correctly by using `location.search` get rid of the error only but if needed `id` value then...? How to retrieve it? I guess getting `id` by storing it somewhere?